# 5 Dashboards 1 list. Need each dashboard edit view to show different list fields

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, list-view, content-editor-web-part, list-view-web-part

I don't have access to the original source code. I can use infopath 2010, sharepoint designer 2010 and access to use CEWPs.  I have 5 Dashboards connected to 1 list. This is just one#

[image] 
Each Dashboard on their own sharepoint page. I have an item based on a choice appear on the dashboard.

[image] 
Using the Edit field in the first column they can go to a majority read only edit page.

[image]

I want to show Buttons changing the status for that particular dashboard. Unfortunately multiple people can be in 3 different dashboards at the same time. Each button set based on the each items status shows on all three dashboards. Like aboves picture. My idea is to create multiple Infopath views but i can't figure how to connect a particular infopath view with that particular page. I know the Edit Dialog toolbar has the option to select which infopath view to use, but i want this to happen automatically. Any Ideas? Does anybody know of a way to do this through the the Content Editor? Or does the edit button create a form load event that shows view based on user group? I know I can do a formload event when they open the form, but can we formload on edit? Sorry these are the ideas i have, but after that i'm dry. Sorry my issue explanation is so long.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this was a little confusing, but it sounds like you have a status field that each of the pages are based on.   You can use this status for a conditional statement in the 'Form Load' section that will pull up the form associated with the current status.  You will need to create the multiple views, and then on each view you may want to add buttons to switch to the other views, in case you are switching inline.  This is because if you load the form and then change the status, it'll no longer swap views until you load the form again.  A button can have a rule associated that will switch views manually.

Comment: Sorry it's hard for me to explain. The 5 dashboards are just seperate modified views of the list view. On form start from button. Sharepoint Designer Workflow sets the status field based on selections in the form fields. If booking has value then hidden booking fields show on the edit view. Problem is i can't figure how to only show those fields for that particular view. I dont want the other view fields to show on the booking edit view if someone is working the other dashboards.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not inline flow. 3 modified views can be worked at a time. based on those selections it may or may not go to another. i have the flow working perfect although the buttons for modified view 1 will show on modified view 2 based on it's status.

Comment: I think we are confusing the our views.  There are views in infopath and sharepoint views.  The sharepoint views are used in different pages with the cewp, but they use some feature that filters them there, hopefully the same status field?  If they are separate fields, it gets a lot harder, because you'll have to think through the conditional logic an use multiple nested statements to pull the correct infopath view.  So you may have several infopath views based on combinations of the fields.  IE if you flag booking and pending, then you'll want a form for that combination.  If that makes sense

Comment: However, if the sharepoint views are sorted by one status field, then you just build out a view for each of those in infopath, only showing in that view the fields you want to show.  Then using the form load rule, when they load the form, they see the view associated with the current status.

Comment: So does hitting the edit button in the list view constitute a formload? Because that's the only way i know how to open the list view item.

Comment: If two people are working one list item in different dashboards with one status field wouldn't the users be overiding each other out?

Comment: Also if pressing edit button creates a formload then just assigning a usergroup on formload to a infopath view might be easier right?

Comment: The thing is, even if they are accessing it from different pages, they are accessing the same list, so if they are both editing the same item, then there is going to be some conflict.  And yes, hitting the edit button is considered 'form load' you also have 'form submit' which might be able to be configured to check to see if the item had been updated since the session started.  That could then be used to throw a flag saying hey this item has changed are you sure you want to commit your changes?

Comment: As far as the usergroup thing, yea that is one option as well.  You could also lock the item for editing on form load which would help prevent conflicts.  So you have options, you just need to decide what will work best for your environment.

Comment: I would so like some way to just go and set a specific InfoPath view with the form load in sharepoint designer and then set a different InfoPath view same sharepoint list different page. Or a magical java code to enter into a CEWP that will on edit select force choose from the "InfoPath view" dropdown n the edit item tool bar. You have given me some possibilities. Ill see what I can do and come back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So based on Oddity's answer which i couldn't do because of multiple users simultaneously utilizing 1 of the 5 dashboards, i morphed his answer to instead of based on status (Which i will have to have 5 seperate statuses for other hidden sections and info) to based on auto assigned user field. So I already have a people picker that prepopulates with user info, using formload if that prepopulated picker's DisplayName contains Cooper then switch view to one of 5 other views. It works. I should have thought of it as simple as it actually is. Thanks for your help Oddity.